# No more login to Google Drive in TWebBrowser: "this browser or app may not be secure."

Tags: rest, google-chrome, google-drive-api, webbrowser-control

Our app uses the TWebBrowser control from Delphi 10.1 and tries to login to Google Drive using the OAuth2 method (REST.Authenticator.OAuth.WebForm.Win). That worked fine for years.

Now Google obviously considers the TWebBrowser control outdated, giving the message: "This browser or app may not be secure."

I have tried the following potential remedies:

1. Setting FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION in the registry (works for Google maps)
2. Setting the global session header in the REST FormCreate event:

   ```
   UserAgent:= 'User-Agent: Chrome/96.0.4664.93';
   UrlMkSetSessionOption(URLMON_OPTION_USERAGENT, Pchar(UserAgent), Length(UserAgent), 0);
   ```
3. `WebBrowser.Navigate(URL, null, null, null, 'User-Agent: Chrome/96.0.4664.93');`

None of them work. Did I do something wrong, is there another option, or has Google decided to outdate my Delphi version? Supposedly, updating to Dephi 11 solves the problem by setting TWebBrowser to use the Chrome engine. But I cannot do that at the moment and need a quicker fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try value 11001 for FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION. Works for me in 64bit Windows and Delphi 2006 application using TWebBrowser.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"Project7.exe"=dword:11001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION]
"Project7.exe"=dword:11001
```

Comment: Does not work under Delphi 10.1, Windows 10 64bit, 32bit application.   

This is my code to get an access token:   

   `OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientID:= Trim(gcGDClientID);
    OAuth2Authenticator1.ClientSecret:= Trim(gcGDClientSecret);
    frm_OAuthWebForm.ShowModalWithURL(OAuth2Authenticator1.AuthorizationRequestURI);`    
How are you getting the acces_token? Can you show me your code? (And how on earth can I add line breaks in comments???)